# Using brackets and dashes in Django url regex pattern

Tags: regex, django, unicode

Originally I was using the url pattern:

`url(r'^poi/folder/(?P<doc_type>\w+)/$', ...)`

to capture the `doc_type` parameter which was a string being pulled from a django `models.CharField`, however when I changed the model to use a django `models.SlugField` the pattern would no longer match the string (SlugField returns a unicode string) which focred me to change the pattern to:

`url(r'^poi/folder/(?P<doc_type>[-\w]+)/$', ...`

My question is why does adding brackets and the '-' make the pattern match a unicode string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about Django in particular but I think you are mistaken. The brackets indicate a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) selector in Regular Expressions.

So the difference between the `\w` and `[-\w]` is that:

- `\w` only matches lowercase & uppercase letters as well as numbers and the `_` (underscore symbol) but **not** the `-` (dash symbol)
- the character class `[-\W]` matches everything the `\w` matches plus the `-` (dash symbol)

So most likely the reason why the first regular expression didn't work for your other field but second regular expression did is that there were dashes in the second filed. Not the fact that the field contained Unicode characters.

Comment: Oh duh, this makes so much sense, it's not that the slug was unicode, its that slugs contain '-'. Thanks so much!